# Scrolling recyclerview will not work over the area covered by a clickable imageview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an `ImageView` that is on top of a `RecyclerView` and when you scroll the `RecyclerView`, the image needs to scroll. This works but I also need to allow the image to be clicked. If I set the clickable attribute to true in the `XML` layout, the image will be clickable but if I scroll on the image, the `RecyclerView` no longer scrolls. The `ImageView` is clearly intercepting the scroll events but not passing them on to the `RecyclerView`. How can I pass the scroll events on to the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: Paste some code, perhaps some pics.

Comment: Can you try with addOnScrollChangeListener() of recyclerview  ? or paste your efforts and pics